# $\langle f,g\rangle_H$ is $\mu$-mesurable

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, separable-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $(X,\mu,\mathcal{A})$ a $\sigma$-finite, complete measure space. My textbook states that $L_2(X,\mu,H)$ together with $$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2\colon L_2(X,\mu,H)^2\to\mathbb{K},\quad (f,g)\mapsto\int_X\langle f,g\rangle_H\, d\mu$$
is a hilbert space and that this would be obvious using some result  $(\star)$ and Hölder's inequality.

This is not obvious to me as I fail to see how, given $f=[f'],g=[g']\in L_2(X,\mu,H)$, it is$\langle f',g'\rangle_H\in\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,\mathbb{K})$:  I know that $(f',g')\in\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,H^2)$. The result $(\star)$ states that

> In separable Banach spaces $E$, $F$, given $u\in\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,E)$, $v\in\mathcal{C}(f(X), F)$, it is $u\circ v\in\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,F)$.

However, $E=H^2$ is not assumed to be separable, so how is this result applicable?

Comment: So $f$ and $g$ are functions with values in a Hilbert space $H$ and $\int_X  \langle f, g \rangle \, d\mu$ means $\int_X \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle \, d\mu(x)$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, $(\langle f,g \rangle\colon x\mapsto \langle f(x),g(x)\rangle)$.

Comment: And the problem you have is why $x \mapsto \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle \in L_1(X, \mu, \mathbb K)$?

Comment: @md2perpe It would suffice for me to know that that map is in $\mathcal{L}_0(X,\mu,\mathbb{K})$, that is that it is $\mu$-mesurable.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the method used by [Folland](https://books.google.se/books?id=AnIPAQAAMAAJ) to prove that $fg$ is measurable if $f$ and $g$ are, and think that the same method can be applied to this case.

Let $f,g : X \to H$ be fixed and let $h : X \to \mathbb K$ be defined by $h(x) = \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle$. Then we can write $h = \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \circ p$ where $p: X \to H^2$ is given by $p(x) = (f(x), g(x))$.

Now, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : H^2 \to \mathbb K$ is continuous and therefore measurable $(\mathcal B_{H^2}, \mathcal B_{\mathbb K})$-measurable. Here $\mathcal B_Y$ denotes the Borel-sets on $Y$. Also, $p$ is $(\mathcal B_X, \mathcal B_{H^2})$-measurable (here $\mathcal B_X = \mathcal A$ according to your notation) as a tuple of $(\mathcal B_X, \mathcal B_{H})$-measurable functions. Then the composition $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \circ p$ is $(\mathcal B_X, \mathcal B_{\mathbb K})$-measurable.

Comment: In the general case I am considering, continuity is not enough for a function to be measurable. The function needs to be $\mu$-almost separable, too.
So, I need to know that $h$ is not only continuous but that there is also some $\mu$-null set $N$ such that $h(N^c)$ is separable.

Comment: Because $\mathcal A$ is not necessarily a Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, $X$ is not assumed to be a topological space, but even if it was, $\mathcal{A}\supset \mathcal{B}_X$ would not imply a continuous map to be $\mu$-almost separable. (I think)